# Original Question being marked as the duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicates

May be this is not really a big issue. But it took my attention because it was done by a moderator of the site.

My question is what can we do, if a the original question is marked as a duplicate of question which has been posted later?

The [question here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26900/how-to-get-the-json-interface-abi-in-new-remix-ide-version/26926#26926) has been marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27820/no-bytecode-no-abi-code-showed-in-the-remix) which has been posted later. This can be considered as okay if the later question has an accepted answer at least which justify the statement of duplicate marking

> This question already has an answer here:

, but it also doesn't have an answer.

All I did was to flag to moderator attention.

Comment: I see the flag but will let Badr check (mods should generally avoid undoing actions by other mods).

Comment: @eth yes, it sounds more ethical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right i have mistakenly marked this question as duplicated.
Generally if one of your questions gets closed as duplicated you can flag for moderator attention and ask for reopening.

Comment: Cool, Thanks for the reply  :)